# How to leverage a spark cluster from a web app?

Tags: apache-spark

A lot of people have asked this question but there is no clear answer except links and references and also most of them are not recent. The question is this :
I have a web app that needs to leverage a spark cluster to run a spark-sql query. My understanding is that submit-job script is asynchronous hence this won't work here. How do I leverage spark in such a setup? Can I just write code in the web app like I do in a self-contained spark application i.e. create a context, set the master URL and do what I need to do ? Will this work in a web app ? If yes, then when would I need the job server that provides REST APIs to submit jobs?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to run Spark applications from your webapp using code?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 0):

**Library for launching Spark applications.**

This library allows applications to launch Spark programmatically. There's only one entry point to the library - the **SparkLauncher** class.

To launch a Spark application, just instantiate a *SparkLauncher* and configure the application to run. For example:

```
import org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher;

   public class MyLauncher {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       Process spark = new SparkLauncher()
         .setAppResource("/my/app.jar")
         .setMainClass("my.spark.app.Main")
         .setMaster("local")
         .setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_MEMORY, "2g")
         .launch();
       spark.waitFor();
     }
   }
```

References:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/package-summary.html

Comment: I have read in other posts in this forum that the SparkLauncher solution works only with master set to local. Does it work in cluster mode as well?

Comment: I have submitted YARN applications in cluster mode through it. It works fine

Comment: That is good to know. How do I get the results back synchronously from the launched application ?

Comment: You can get the results using your driver program code if you intend to pull the results back to Driver, else you will store/push the results in some store and fetch from there.

Comment: When you say "get the results using your driver program code"  - you mean, get the results from some persistent store that the app will write to? When does spark.waitFor() return after launching the job or after the job completes ?

Comment: What Spark version you are using and what Spark context you will be using?

Comment: Spark 2.0 built for hadoop 2.7.It will be a 3 node cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I think options will be

- Through rest api like Livy (Livy is a new open source Spark REST
  Server for submitting and interacting with your Spark jobs from
  anywhere. ) or spark server (REST APIs) - See how they connect to
  spark interactively from using kernel -
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TD1J7MzYcFo&feature=youtu.be&t=33m19s

  https://developer.ibm.com/open/apache-toree/
- Through jdbc (Running via the Thrift JDBC/ODBC server)
- Through ssh and submit a job and wait for yarn status (this will
  be SSH to the    cluster and do a spark submit through YARN - YARN
  give you an    application ID and you can keep track of application
  status with yarn    application status command)

Comment: By spark server , do you mean the spark job server or is this something else?  Is the JDBC option through the spark thrift server ? Can you elaborate how the third option can be used programmatically ?Is it possible to submit to a cluster from code , wait and get a response that can be returned to the front end ?